# Removing double insulated glass from single hung aluminum frame

Tags: windows

I want to remove a fogged double pane glass from a single hung window. It is the top unit of the  window and is fixed.

I cut off the vinyl glazing stops on exterior of windows, exposing the pane glass unit. But from inside the house there are 2 horizontal aluminum strips which are part of the window frame, one located on top, and other located on bottom. The glass is glued to the aluminum stops with silicone.

I am unable to separate the glass from the aluminum strip by inserting a putty knife or sharp blade. Are there any suggestions on separating them without deforming the aluminum strip as it seems to be part of the frame?

---

Here are a couple of pics showing the horizontal strip.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Some pictures of the frame would be really helpful here.

Comment: On these types of windows you would commonly need to remove the entire sash to service/replace the glass panes, and you would need to actually remove the sash frame pieces from the glass, rather than removing the glass from the frame. In other words, complete disassembly including removal of the lower sash (the movable one) to access a removable mullion between the two sashes. BTW, some are not designed to be serviceable at all!

Comment: Ouch! So close yet so far. Seemed like just a matter of separating the glue between  the 2 aluminum strips and the window pane. Was almost tempted to shatter the glass, but may have to just let this go. Thanks for the reply.